# 'runtime_error' from c++ not captured in iOS

Tags: c++, ios, swift, objective-c, runtime-error

In my iOS project, I use a C++ module. The C++ module throws exception for some cases and the Objective C++ wrapper fails to catch it. For instance

Here is my `HelloWorld.h`

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class HelloWorld{
public:
    string helloWorld();
};

#endif
```

Implementation `HelloWorld.cpp`

```
#include "HelloWorld.h"

string HelloWorld::helloWorld(){
    throw (std::runtime_error("runtime_error")); // Throwing exception to test
    string s("Hello from CPP");
    return s;
}
```

Objective C++ wrapper `HelloWorldIOSWrapper.h`

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface HelloWorldIOSWrapper:NSObject

- (NSString*)getHello;

@end

#endif /* HelloWorldIOSWrapper_h */
```

Implementation `HelloWorldIOSWrapper.mm`

```
#import "HelloWorldIOSWrapper.h"
#include "HelloWorld.h"

@implementation HelloWorldIOSWrapper

- (NSString*)getHello{
    try {
        HelloWorld h;
        NSString *text=[NSString stringWithUTF8String: h.helloWorld().c_str()];
        return text;
    } catch (const std::exception & e) {
        NSLog(@"Error %s", e.what());
    }
    return nil;
}

@end
```

`#import "HelloWorldIOSWrapper.h"` is added to the `Bridging-Header`

And now, when I try to invoke `getHello()` from controller, app crashes leaving the below message in log

```
libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::runtime_error: runtime_error
dyld4 config: DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/system/introspection DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/Developer/usr/lib/libBacktraceRecording.dylib:/Developer/usr/lib/libMainThreadChecker.dylib:/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DTDDISupport.framework/libViewDebuggerSupport.dylib
terminating with uncaught exception of type std::runtime_error: runtime_error
```

I expect that the exception must be caught in the wrapper, but, no idea why is it not caught leading to app crash. What do I miss?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[C++ Interoperability](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Exceptions/Articles/Exceptions64Bit.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009044-SW1)

> In 64-bit processes, Objective-C exceptions (NSException) and C++
> exception are interoperable. Specifically, C++ destructors and
> Objective-C @finally blocks are honored when the exception mechanism
> unwinds an exception. In addition, default catch clauses—that is,
> catch(...) and @catch(...)—can catch and rethrow any exception
>
> On the other hand, an Objective-C catch clause taking a dynamically
> typed exception object (@catch(id exception)) can catch any
> Objective-C exception, but cannot catch any C++ exceptions. **So, for
> interoperability, use @catch(...) to catch every exception and @throw;
> to rethrow caught exceptions.** In 32-bit, @catch(...) has the same
> effect as @catch(id exception).

```
@try {
} 
@catch (...) {
}
```